# ViewState size get bigger and bigger, is this a updatepanel's bug or not?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

[image: when ddl select changes autopostback]

there's a table and some ddl in updatepanel.

like this:
[image: asp.net page structure]

why this happens???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that **you forget to reset your drop down list and you place them again and again data**.

So two thinks you can do. Use the IsPostBack for populate your dropdownlist and not populate them again if there is a post back, or on every post back, first clear the dropdown items them  add again the list.

For fast check if the dropdownlist is the case, set `enableviewstate="false"` on them